# Getting Uninitialized Constant Error in Ruby Program - why can't I format a number?

Tags: ruby

This field

```
  def format_to_two_dec(stringfield)
    "%.2f" % stringfield # -> CRASHES
    stringfield #--> OKAY - returns a string such as 900
  end
```

This code calls a record with a field called total in it.

```
 return_method =
  proc do |the_self_ref|
    the_record = the_self_ref.peek_next_db_record.select do |an_elem|
      an_elem[:crectype] == '0004'
    end
    the_self_ref.format_to_two_dec(the_record[0][:total])
  end
```

What I'm trying to do is to format the number to have two decimals and ALWAYS two decimals (so 900.00).

The error I get is:

//Scripts/create_835_record.rb:168:in `block (2 levels) in eval_x12_commands': uninitialized constant Create835Records::C (NameError)

The format of the record is:

```
record0004_format =
  {
    ctotal_charge: 15,
    cdiscount: 15,
    cineligible: 15,
    cpended: 15,
    callowed: 15,
    cdeductible: 15,
    ccopay: 15,
    ccoinsurance: 15,
    cbalance: 15,
    cother_carrier: 15,
    cpayment: 15,
    cpatient_responsibility: 15,
    primarypayment: 15,
    excess: 15,
    noncovered: 15
  }

 def eval_x12_commands
    @list_of_segments_in_file.each do |a_cmd|
      array_to_eval = a_cmd.split('|')
      list_of_evaled = []
      array_to_eval.each do |item|
        **list_of_evaled << eval(item, binding)** //this line
      end
      the_method = @the_builder_for835.method(list_of_evaled[0])
      begin
        the_method.call(*list_of_evaled[1..-1])
      rescue
        puts "Eval Exception\n"
      end
    end
```

I hope this will be enough - the program is a bit big, but I can post more if I need to.

Comment: Which is line number 168 (the one reported in the error)? It says there is an uninitialised constant `C`, but nothing in the code above seems to reference anything called `C`?

Comment: What's the value of `item` when the error is raised? It sounds like its value is `"C"` (or some string that contains `C`) and `eval("C", binding)` is raising an error because there's no constant accessible from `binding` named `C`. What's the expected behavior here?

Comment: **WARNING**: `eval` is a huge liability, can cause catastrophic problems, and should be avoided whenever possible. Can you explain what purpose it serves here? In Ruby you can usually do something else that's way less dangerous to achieve the same result.

Comment: In Ruby comments begin with the character `"#"`, not `"//"`. If you added `"//"` as part of the description (but didn't run it with that), you should change them to `"#"` to avoid the confusion.